# Can you please to explain how to use the Record controller in jmeter for web application?

Tags: jmeter

I want to know any specified link to know about record controller

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

1. User Manual [entry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. JMeter Proxy Step by Step [guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
3. JMeter Browser Recording Tutorial [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYAiBwJK1v8)
4. How To Use JMeter To Record Test Scenarios [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios)

Hopefully that's enough to start with.